# In php, increment number is something wrong

Tags: php

I made writer : comment pair programing.
So from $4 to $5 is the first pair of comments. 
$arr[even] (>= 4) is username, $arr[odd] (>=5) is a comment of $arr[odd-1], that is a writer name.

So I am writing the php code.

```
 for ($i=4;$i<count($arr)-1;$i+=2) {
        $name = $arr[$i];

        $comment = $arr[$i++];
        echo $name."<img src='./avatar/".$name.".png' title='".$name."' style='width:19px;height:19px;'> ".$comment."</br>";  
                    }
```

But, that's results is not my thinking.
[image]

I want the below picture.
[image]

I am waiting for your kind advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a [post increment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php) in the comment(`$i++`), so this will use the value and then increment it.  So this means that they both use the same value of `$i` in...

```
   $name = $arr[$i];
   $comment = $arr[$i++];
```

As you are incrementing the value of `$i` in the loop, I would just do...

```
   $name = $arr[$i];
   $comment = $arr[$i+1];
```